# Direct download for free products in Easy Digital Downloads

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

How can i allow users to directly download( no checkout page ) the files that are free in Easy Digital Downloads Plugin?
I want something like this :

```
<?php 
    if( edd_get_download_price( get_the_ID() ) == 0 ) {
        $download_link = DIRECT_DOWNLOAD_URL;
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $download_link; ?>" class="download-button">Download Now!</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help , i really need this , thanks

Comment: can't you do what you've exampled? get the download URL from the database and get the product price from the database and make a comparison to zero? What have you tried already?

Comment: The condition works, it detects free products , i just need something that skips the checkout page , and directly goes for download

Comment: Is there a custom field or something for download links ?

Comment: You would have to construct something from the information in the database. But you'd need a easy-digitial-downloads guy to give you details, I don't know that software I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks like this was asked on the support forum for this Wordpress Plugin. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-just-have-free-downloads. Maybe that will help you out.

Comment: @john Thank you , i found this plugin in the link you gave me : https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads-free-download/ It's exactly what i want , thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help , I found this Plugin : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads-free-download/
It's great!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin as well - https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads-free-link/

I have used in few clients website and it works great!!